# How to use field value within CRUD Controller

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-backpack

I am new to Backpack and Laravel and am hoping you can help me solve an issue I am stuck on...

I have a text field in my Create/Update CRUD that is used to save the user's social network.

I added an icon as a suffix to this field and am trying to make it a link to that social network, with the input the user has entered.

The code for the field looks something like this:

```
CRUD::addField([
  'name' => 'linkedin', 
  'type' => 'text', 
  'label' => 'LinkedIn', 
  'prefix' => 'https://www.linkedin.com/in/',
  'suffix' => "<a href='https://www.linkedin.com/in/".$socialNetwork."' target='_blank'><i class='la la-linkedin'></i></a>",
  'tab' => 'Social',
 ],
);
```

I am hoping to set $socialNetwork with the value the user has in the input of this field.

I have tried using the JS Library to do this but I can only update other fields. I need to set a variable in the JS file that I can then use in the controller, but I am not managing to do that.

Here is an example of the JS script used:

```
let socialNetwork = 'xyz';
crud.field('linkedin').onChange(function(field) {
     socialNetwork = field.value;
}).change();
```

I then add the JS to the controller using a Widget

```
Widget::add()->type('script')->content('assets/js/myscript.js');
```

...but I cannot access the variable. I get a variable is undefined error from Laravel.

Comment: Perhaps because you're re-using `let`? If `socialNetwork` is already defined on-top, and used elsewhere in your code, remove the `let` declaration.

Comment: I tried with and without. I tried setting let outside the change function and then not using it within. I always get an error from Laravel that the variable is undefined.

Comment: Than you should show where **and how** you use that variable exactly

Comment: I updated the description. Does that make more sense?

Answer (score 0):

I think instead of passing the variable, since you already got the value, you should target the input prefix directly.

Something like this should work:

```js
crud.field('linkedin').onChange(function(field) {
// get the field prefix element
let fieldPrefix = crud.field('linkedin').$input.parent().find('.input-group-text');
 //set the value you want there:
fieldPrefix.html('<a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/'+field.value+'" target="_blank"><i class="la la-linkedin"></i></a>');
}).change();
```

Hope it helps, cheers!

Comment: This is perfect!!! TYSM